# Decode string using UTF-8 in swift 5

Tags: swift, utf-8

I have String swift 5. string is like bellow..

```
Kawran Bazar FDC Road, East Nakhalpara, à¦¨à¦¿à¦à§à¦¤à¦¨, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾ à¦¬à¦¿à¦­à¦¾à¦, à¦¬à¦¾à¦à¦²à¦¾à¦¦à§à¦¶
```

I need to convert it. I tried it like bellow

```
 let data = location_name.data(using: .utf8)
  var str =  String(decoding:data!, as: UTF8.self)
    print("location_name***",str)
```

But need to convert string bellow like from above

```
Kawran Bazar FDC Road, East Nakhalpara, নিকেতন, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ
```

How to solve the problem

Comment: What is the output of `print("location_name***",str)` ?

Comment: @koen it is like East Nakhalpara, à¦¨à¦¿à¦à§à¦¤à¦¨, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾ à¦¬à¦¿à¦­à¦¾à¦, à¦¬à¦¾à¦à¦²à¦¾à¦¦à§à¦¶

Comment: Try `let data = location_name.data(using: .nonLossyASCII); let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: @koen it is now like Optional("Bismillah Hotel \\340\\246\\254\\340\\246\\277\\340\\246\\270\\340\\246\\256\\340\\246\\277\\340\\246\\262\\340\\247\\215\\340\\246\\262\\340\\246\\276\\340\\246\\271

Comment: Interesting, so where does "Bismillah Hotel" come from, it is not in your expected output. Are you sure the input is correct?

Comment: @koen dear sir, My data is not fixed. Every 10 second it change..But output is above like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the output you get if at some point UTF-8 data was interpreted as Latin1. For example:

```
let s = "Kawran Bazar FDC Road, East Nakhalpara, নিকেতন, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ"
let utf8Data = Data(s.utf8)
let latin1 = String(data: utf8Data, encoding: .isoLatin1)!
print(latin1)

==> 

Kawran Bazar FDC Road, East Nakhalpara, à¦¨à¦¿à¦à§à¦¤à¦¨, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾ à¦¬à¦¿à¦­à¦¾à¦, à¦¬à¦¾à¦à¦²à¦¾à¦¦à§à¦¶
```

You should first try to fix this and remove this incorrect string creation. If you cannot, then you can round-trip it back through Latin1.

```
let latin1Data = latin1.data(using: .isoLatin1)!
let utf8String = String(data: latin1Data, encoding: .utf8)!

utf8String == s // true
```